# Webpack: Why does devserver generate a "chunk_vendors.js" and the build "node_vendors.js" (this is the name I configured)

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I am pretty happy with my webpack config in `vue.config.js` but I have this weird behavior with dev server: the main vendor files is named "node_vendors" (see below) but when I do `vue-cli-service serve` I end up with a `chunk_vendors.js` and I can’t understand why

Is it a normal behavior ? Have I missed something in the configuration ?

Thanks a lot !

```
cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        name: 'node_vendors',
        // Modules inside ((?!(foo|bar).*) are excluded
        test: new RegExp(
          `[\\\\/]node_modules[\\\\/]((?!(${excludedFromCommonVendor.join(
            '|'
          )})).*)[\\\\/]`
        ),
        chunks: 'all'
      },
```

Comment: Can you share the full the content of `vue.config.js`?

Comment: sure thing : https://pastebin.com/pZuyKXcP

Comment: I tried to replicate with my simple app created by `vue-cli` but it works fine though which means no issue like you above